# jQueryUI autocomplete in Bootstrap modal displaying underneath modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete, jqmodal

I have a jQueryUI autocomplete in a Bootstrap modal window. When I run it normally in the page it works fine, but when I try add it into the modal the list appears behind the modal, not in front.

I've tried variations of the following with no luck:

```
$("#myModal").css("z-index", "1500"); 
$("tags'.$fieldname.'").css("z-index", "5000");
```

In the modal:

```
data-backdrop="false"
```

Here is the source:

```
<!-- RFQ Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="z-index:2000;">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body" data-backdrop="false"  >

      <script>
      $(function ps2() {        

      var availableTagsps2 = [
      {label:"3rd It Tech (IS# 20)", value:20},{label:"SeaBreeze Computers (IS# 14)", value:14},{label:"SeaBreeze Computers (IS# 14)", value:14},{label:"SeaBreeze Computers (IS# 14)", value:14},{label:"SeaBreeze Computers (IS# 14)", value:14},{label:"SeaBreeze Computers (IS# 14)", value:14},{label:"SeaBreeze Computers (IS# 14)", value:14} 

      ];

      $("#tagsps2").autocomplete({
           source: availableTagsps2

      });

  $( "#tagsps2" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTagsps2,
            select: function ps2(event, ui) {
            var selectedObj = ui.item;
            $(this).val(selectedObj.label);
            $('input[name="ps2"]').val(selectedObj.value);

            return false;
        }

    });
/* $("#myModal").css("z-index","6000"); 
$("#tagsps2").css("z-index","20000");*/
  });

  </script>

  <input type="text" id="tagsps2"  required  AutoComplete="off" placeholder="Search..." 
  class="inputMed inline form-control input-med"  />
  <input type="hidden" name="ps2" value=""  />

        <div class="row" >
              <div class="col-md-6">
              <form role="form">
                  <div class="form-group" >

                    <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Select client" required> -->
                  </div>

                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
                </form>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-6">

                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                    <a href="dashboard.php?vrfq" class="light">View Sent RFQ's</a>
                    </button>
                </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<!-- end modal -->

    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><div class="RightCounter">&    nbsp;</div><h2>RFQ</h2></a>
```

Comment: Can you create a http://www.bootply.com/ demonstrating the issue?  I can't get the autocomplete to work using your source.

Answer (score 52):

Using Bootstrap 3.1.1 I found it sufficient just to add the following CSS to get the autocomplete to work.

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    z-index: 5000;
}
```

The ui-autocomplete class is attached to the UL which is used internally to construct the autocomplete.  By giving it a crazy high z-index you effectively ensure it will be laid out above everything else in the page including the modal dialog.

Comment: sometimes I think how the life would have been without SO and without well-wishers like you...thanks a ton!

Comment: Simplest Solution and this may be accepted as answer

Answer (score 24):

jQuery autocomplete has a built in CSS class for this purpose. Just add 'ui-front' class to a container element in the Bootstrap modal.

[jQuery Autocomplete docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-appendTo)

> .. the parents of the input field will be checked for a class of
>   ui-front. If an element with the ui-front class is found, the menu
>   will be appended to that element

Comment: This is much nicer than setting the z-index.

Answer (score 3):

Use **appendTo** option instead css modifications:
http://api.jqueryui.com/1.10/autocomplete/#option-appendTo

Comment: This worked for me where other answers did not.  To make it more clear, I added
<div id="autocompleteAppendToMe"></div> directly below my input, then I added appendTo: "#autocompleteAppendToMe"  to my JavaScript declaration of the jquery ui autocomplete.  This makes the menu pop out of that div where ever you put it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("tags'.$fieldname.'").css("zIndex", 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me:

```
<input type="text" id="country"  class="form-control" onclick="data()" />
```

and then in javascript:

```
        var countries = [
    { value: 'Andorra', data: 'AD' },
    { value: 'Zimbabwe', data: 'ZZ' }
    ]; 

     function data(){
    $('#country').autocomplete({
    lookup: countries,
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
    }
   });

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Try adding following:

Below Input field of tags, add a div with `id="tags_container"`
like this:

```
<input type="text" id="tagsps2"  required  AutoComplete="off" placeholder="Search..." class="inputMed inline form-control input-med"  />
<div id="container_tags">
</div>
```

Then add following css:

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    position: absolute;
}

#container_tags {
    display: block; 
    position:relative
}
```

This should fix your alignment issue.

Answer (score 0):

I needed both of the answers from glastonbridge and bsandhu to make this work, as the 'ui-front' class only adds a z-index of 100.

Also, the "ui-front" class needed to be on a div that immediately wrapped my input control to get consistent results.

I'm using BS 3.3.7, jQ 3.1.1, and jQUI 1.12.1.